# Deleting a branch that has a detached head - Will i lose the head?

Tags: git

I have a branch that has got very messy, it was lots of versions behind the master, i pulled into it and i just want to delete it.

I have a detached head of this branch that I've been working on, if I delete the branch, will I lose the detached head?

Comment: The detached HEAD isn't an actual commit, unless you make one or more commits from that point.  If you _have_ made some commits from the detached HEAD state, then they should still be visible in the reflog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git kind of overloads the word "head", and this may be leading you astray.  Though, to be fair, Git badly overloads the word "branch", too.  To help keep them straight, let's use the phrase *branch name* here.

The word `HEAD`—spelled exactly like this, in all uppercase<sup>1</sup>—means both *the current commit* and *the current branch name*.  Well, more precisely, it *always* means current-commit, and when *attached*, it *also* means current-branch-name.

To make this work, Git usually—*usually*—stores *the name of a branch* in its `HEAD`.  Then the *branch name* identifies the commit!  So `HEAD` holds the name of a branch, and the branch-name holds the commit hash ID.

---

<sup>1</sup>Just to make things confusing, on Windows and MacOS, you can use lowercase as well, but that's a side effect of the fact that when you ask Windows or MacOS to open the file `readme` and there exists a file named `README`, they open the uppercase-named file.  Git stores its idea of your `HEAD` in a file named `HEAD`.  If you like, take a look at the file: `cat .git/HEAD` for instance.  It always contains just one line, and usually that one line is `ref: refs/heads/<name>`.

---

#### Drawing branches

It's actually the commit hash ID that is all-important for working with the branch itself!  It helps, I think, to *draw* this.  Suppose you start with a tiny little repository that has only three commits in it.  They all have some big ugly hash ID, unique to each commit, but to make this manageable, let's just call them commits `A`, `B`, and `C`, where `A` is the first commit you ever made, `B` is the second, and `C` is the third.

Now, each commit remembers, inside its read-only, saved-forever data, the hash ID of the commit that comes *before* it.  Since `A` is the *first* commit, nothing comes before it, so it stands by itself.  Since `B` comes after `A`, `B` remembers `A`'s ID: we say that `B` *points to* `A`.  Similarly, `C` remembers, i.e., points to, `B`:

```
A  <-B  <-C
```

What Git needs to know now is the hash ID for commit `C`—the *end* of the chain of commits.  This is where *branch names* come in.  Let's use the name `master` to point to commit `C`, by storing the actual hash ID of `C` in the name `master`.  And for a reason that will become obvious in one moment, let's draw the commits like this:

```
    C   <-- master
   /
  B
 /
A
```

Now, without changing the set of *commits* in your repository, let's attach another branch name `dev` to commit `B` rather than `C`:

```
    C   <-- master
   /
  B   <-- dev
 /
A
```

How will Git know *which commit* is the *current commit*, and *which branch name* is the current *branch*?  This is where `HEAD` comes in.  Let's draw the name `HEAD` in, and attach it to branch `dev`:

```
    C   <-- master
   /
  B   <-- dev (HEAD)
 /
A
```

#### Making new commits while HEAD is attached, or, how branches work

Now let's look at the secret to how branches actually work in Git.  Working with this same sequence of commits, with `HEAD` attached to `dev`, let's make a *new* commit.  As with all commits, Git will save a snapshot of all of our files, and give this new snapshot a new, unique, big ugly hash ID, but we'll just call it `D`.

The new commit `D` has to remember the *current* commit.  How do we find the current commit?  Yes, that's right: we look at `HEAD`!  It's attached to `dev` and `dev` points to `B`, so `B` is the current commit.  This means our new commit `D` has to point back to `B`:

```
    C
   /
  B--D
 /
A
```

And, now that we have new commit `D` as the *tip* of our development branch, Git simply writes `D`'s hash ID into the *name* `dev`.  But how does Git know to use the name `dev`?  If you said: *Git looks at `HEAD`*, congratulations, you've just understood how an attached `HEAD` works!  Let's put the labels back in:

```
    C   <-- master
   /
  B--D   <-- dev (HEAD)
 /
A
```

Note that we can draw this graph any way we like, as long as we remember that:

- Git works *backwards*.  It starts from the attached `HEAD` to get the branch name, then from the branch name, Git finds the *tip* commit of the branch.
- Each commit points *backwards*, to its parent.  Git follows the backwards link to the next—previous?—commit in the chain.
- The action stops when either we get tired of following along, or we reach a commit that can't go back any further: commit `A`, a *root* commit.

So:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
    \
     D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

or:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B
    \
     D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

are all valid ways to draw this graph.  The *branch names*, `master` and `dev`, identify the *tip* commits, and from there Git works backwards through the rest of the commits.

Note that commits `B` and `A` are on *both branches*.  The last drawing makes this super-clear, and hence is sometimes the way to go.  It's also clear what happens if we add a new name, like `m2`, that points to commit `C` just like `master`:

```
     C   <-- master, m2
    /
A--B
    \
     D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Now commits `A-B-C` are on *both* branches, `master` *and* `m2`.  We can safely delete one of the two names, because we can still use the other name to find commit `C`.

#### A detached HEAD

So, if your HEAD is normally *attached* to a branch name—the file `.git/HEAD` contains the name of the branch—what exactly is a *detached HEAD?*  That, too, is really simple, as it turns out.  A detached HEAD occurs when the file `.git/HEAD` contains, instead of a *branch name*, a raw *commit hash ID*.  Let's use the last graph drawing again, but now split `HEAD` from `dev` and make `HEAD` itself point *straight to commit `B`:*

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B   <-- HEAD
    \
     D   <-- dev
```

Now, from here, let's add a *new* commit, by the usual method of modifying some files and `git add` and `git commit`.  Git will make a new commit, with a new big ugly hash ID, but we will just call it `E`.  Commit `E` will point back to `B` as usual ... and then Git will write `E`'s hash ID into `HEAD`, rather than into some branch name, giving:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B--E   <-- HEAD
    \
     D   <-- dev
```

#### The commits are what matter; the names are how Git finds the commits

Suppose you have the above, with the detached `HEAD` pointing to `E`.  Now suppose you delete the branch name `dev`:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B--E   <-- HEAD
    \
     D   ???
```

What happens to commit `D`?  In some sense, it's still there, but now there is no obvious way to *find* it.  Let's put `dev` back, and this time, let's re-attach `HEAD` to it:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B--E   ???
    \
     D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

What happens to commit `E`?  Again, it's still *there*, but there is no obvious way to *find* it.  So *before* we re-attach `HEAD` to `dev` or `master`, let's make some *branch name* point to commit `E`.  That is, let's go back to:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B--E   <-- HEAD
    \
     D   <-- dev
```

and run `git branch temp` or `git checkout -b temp`.  What these do is create a *new name*, `temp`, pointing to the *current commit*:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B--E   <-- temp, HEAD
    \
     D   <-- dev
```

or:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B--E   <-- temp (HEAD)
    \
     D   <-- dev
```

The difference between these two is whether `HEAD` is *attached*.  Using `git branch` makes the new name, without attaching `HEAD` to it.  Using `git checkout -b` makes the new name, *and* attaches `HEAD` to it.

#### Summary

That's it—it's really that simple!  The *branch names* point to the tip commits, and `HEAD` remembers one of the branch names.  Or, if you have a detached HEAD, `HEAD` remembers one of the commits directly.

The *commits* are what matter, but Git finds them using the names as starting (or ending?) points.  Adding a *new* commit *automatically* updates the current branch *name* to point to the new final commit for that branch.  Or rather, it does that if `HEAD` is attached to a branch!  You can and should expect branch names to move forward in this manner.

Not covered here, but important: if there is *no* name for some commit—if there is no way to find commit `E`, for instance, because we made it on a detached HEAD and never made a *name* for it before re-attaching our HEAD somewhere else—the commit becomes vulnerable to Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`.  Commits are normally *protected* from this kind of collection for at least 30 days from when you last were able to see them via `HEAD`, but they become really hard to find if there's no obvious name.  But this Grim <strike>Reaper</strike> Collector, `git gc`, will generally *remove* unwanted commits after a month or so.  This is, for instance, how `git rebase` works: `git rebase` *copies* commits, then—by moving the *branch name* a la `git branch -f`—abandons the original commits in favor of the newer, shinier copies.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to supply so much information, wow! I read it all, it turns out it doesnt matter too much where your 'head' is pointing, it's just basically saying that you are currently on a previous commit and that's where your head is, it's just detached from your main branch! :D thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, HEAD can't be "lost". Just checkout anything else to get a brand new target for the mere pointer that HEAD is.

---

About the recent commits :

Like Tim mentionned in his comment, you can get them back from your reflog.

However, if you're unsure about losing these commits and want to somehow keep them around, create a backup branch where your detached HEAD is currently pointing to.

```
# let's create a memory of your currently detached HEAD
git checkout -b sleepyHollow
```

Then just continue working on your master, and if you need a specific commit from the previous messy branch, just cherry-pick it back into master to avoid merging/rebasing hardships. The existence of the backup branch will preserve the "lost" commits from the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to branch off from the head as you suggested, then I will point the original branch to this new one.

Comment: for anyone reading this is the solution to do it: $git checkout –b temp #makes a new branch from current detached HEAD
$git branch –f master temp #update master to point to the new <temp> branch
$git branch –d temp #delete the <temp> branch
$git push origin master #push the re-established history